# 2 UIcollectionview inside a scrollview with dynamic contents

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a scrollview which will consist 2 UIcollectionviews (shown in the screenshot). What I want to do is I wish the scrollable view will expand as the lower part UIcollectionview items increased. So the view can scroll up entirely when the contents of the UIcollectionview expand.
Note that the upper UIcollectionview can be scroll up with the scroll view.
Can someone guide me on what is the method to do that ?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if you hooked the height constraint of the lower one and changed it in code

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
 {
     super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

     self.lowerCollecVHCon.constant = numberOfItems * itemHeight
 }
```

Comment: is there any constraint settings for the scrollview?

Comment: you should hook all constraints properly from top to bottom for items inside scrollView so it can resize itself according to inner change of constraints